# Django and mustaches (using index from laravel)

Tags: jquery, html, django, laravel

I did earlier some laravel site(sass, jQuery, Angular) which now I want to use in django but seems not so easy, got errors at the very beginning.

```
2   <html lang="PL">
3   <head>
4       <meta charset="utf-8">
5       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
6       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
7       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel:400,700,900&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
8       <title>@yield('title')</title>
9   
10  
11      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
12      {{--jQuery--}}
```

Error at line 12

How to make django read this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django has its own [template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#variables) where `{{ ... }}` syntax represents variable expansion which could be the one provided by the corresponding Django view or defined in the template code directly. Thus, when attempting to process the `{{--jquery--}}` directive of yours template engine expectedly fails as `--` construct is unknown to it.

Given that it's imperative for you to actually have `{{--jquery--}}` present in the markup, I suggest you temporatily switch off template rendering by surround this directive with the [`verbatim`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) template tag as follows:

```
    {% verbatim %}
        {{--jquery--}}
    {% endverbatim %}
```